# Windows Phone in-app products ListingInformation.ProductListings does not contain all products

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have Windows phone 8.0 c# application. There are lots of in-app durable products associated with this application (approximately 2000). The application is published and it is possible to buy any of durable product associated with the application on the app store. It works fine.

I would like to refresh all product prices in the application and show list of the actual prices (loaded from the app store).

I use this code:

```
var asyncListingInformation = CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
asyncListingInformation.Completed = (async, status) =>
{
    try
    {
        var listingInformation = async.GetResults();
        int count = 0; // Compute count of returned products

        foreach (var pair in listingInformation.ProductListings)
        {
            string productId = pair.Value.ProductId;
            string price = pair.Value.FormattedPrice;

            this.UpdateProductPrice(productId, price);
            count++;
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(count);  // Returns: 100
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
};
```

The problem is that listingInformation.ProductListings contains only 100 products, but there are much more products on the server.
Where is the problem I can not retrieve more than 100 products? Is there any other way howto load price of specified product from the app store? Application knows all product ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationByProductIdsAsync method.
Your code should be changed:

```
List<string> productIds = new List<string>();
foreach (var product in myProducts) // << Change myProducts and set your collection of products. myProducts contains for example 2000 items.
{
    productIds.Add(product.ProductId);
}

var asyncListingInformation = CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationByProductIdsAsync(productIds);
asyncListingInformation.Completed = (async, status) =>
{
    try
    {
        var listingInformation = async.GetResults();
        int count = 0; // Compute count of returned products

        foreach (var pair in listingInformation.ProductListings)
        {
            string productId = pair.Value.ProductId;
            string price = pair.Value.FormattedPrice;

            this.UpdateProductPrice(productId, price);
            count++;
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(count);  // Returns: 2000 :-)
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
};
```